# Function caching when a property of an object changes

Tags: python

I have a function that I need to cache. The arguments of the function is an object `obj` amongst others. However, I would like to change the property of the object `obj` periodically.

I have tried using functools `lru_cache`.

```
class TestObj:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

@lru_cache(1024)
def print_number(obj):
    return obj.number

obj = TestObj(1)


assert print_number(obj) == 1
obj.number = 2
assert print_number(obj) == 2
```

I would like the second assert statement to be `true`, as I have changed an underlying property of the object `obj`

Comment: This makes no sense. You can just write `obj.number` instead of `print_number(obj)`. Can you come up with a better example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general problem with mutable objects. Whatever caching system you use, the goal of a cache is to give again previous value (without computing it) when given the same parameters.

Here you actually pass the exact same object (true identity given by `is` in Python), so no caching system could guess that its cache is dirty. Here are the common workarounds:

- eject an object from the cache as soon as it is modified. Here that would mean that `number` has to be a property, and that `TestObj` must know of the cache. Not really simple here IMHO
- do not cache `print_number` but make it a wrapper around another function calling the relevant non mutable TestObj members. Trivial here

You would have

```
def print_number(obj):
    return do_print_number(obj.number)


@lru_cache(1024)
def do_print_number(number):
    return number
```

It will work provided `obj.number` is a non mutable object, like a number, a string or a tuple, and neither a list, a set or a map.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your example pretty much defeates the purpose of `lru_cache`.. Anyway, the only way I can think of is to add `print_number.cache_clear()` before your second assertion:

```py
assert print_number(obj) == 1
obj.number = 2
print_number.cache_clear()
assert print_number(obj) == 2
```

Comment: Thanks, and apologies for the simplified example.